# Endomorphism of frobenius scheme

Tags: number-theory, abelian-varieties

Firstly, let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$.

Consider the local-local group scheme
$$\alpha_p=\operatorname{Spec} k[\alpha]/(\alpha^p)\,,$$
then the claim in [Oort's Which Abelian Surfaces are Products of Elliptic Curves](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01428253.pdf) is that 
$$\operatorname{End}_k(\alpha_p)\cong k\,.$$
My question is: why is this true? Surely $\alpha\mapsto\alpha^2$ is also a valid endomorphism; hence on top of the linear transformations, we must have that $\operatorname{End}_k(\alpha_p)$ is greater than $k$.

Background: I would like to count the number of supersingular principally polarised abelian surfaces and stumbled onto this question while reading [Katsura and Oort's paper](https://eudml.org/doc/urn:eudml:doc:89837).

Comment: I haven't checked myself, but are you sure that gives rise to a morphism of hopf algebras?

Comment: @leibnewtz I didn't know that they even had a structure as hopf algebras, so I am definitely not claiming so.

Comment: Well when you say endomorphism do you mean just an endomorphism of schemes or of group schemes? If it's the latter, this is the same thing as a morphism of Hopf algebras. To see why every affine group scheme corresponds to a hopf algebra, just write out the group axioms and reverse the arrows

Comment: @leibnewtz In that case, I mean the endomorphism of group schemes. Thanks for pointing that out.